# How to access parameters List values defined in shared lib from jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have created a shared library `jobParams.groovy` with below content:

```
List commonParams() {
      //return list of parameters
      def paramsList = [
         string(defaultValue: "Jenkins", description: 'Some Name', name: 'NAME'),
         string(defaultValue: "no_title", description: 'Title', name: 'TITLE')
     ]
     return paramsList
   }
```

In the job pipeline script, I read that list into another list, but not sure how to access the desired value from the list, e.g, how to print commonParams.NAME ?

I have this in my job, as pipeline script:

```
@Library('jenkins-library@master') _

List commonParams = jobParams.commonParams()

pipeline {
    agent { label 'my-server' }
    stages {
        stage('params') {
            steps {
                println "commonParams"

            }
        }
}
```

This prints

```
[Pipeline] echo
[@string(defaultValue=Jenkins,description=Some Name,name=NAME), @string(defaultValue=no_title,description=Title,name=TITLE)]
[Pipeline] }
```

below didn't work to print just the NAME.

`println "${commonParams.NAME}"`

Comment: It's a list. You have to find required param in a list. Something like `params.find{it.name=='NAME'}`

Answer (score 0):

You can create class with static method

```
// file: /src/com/company/jenkins/JobParam.groovy
package com.company.jenkins

class JobParam {
  static List commonParams() {
      //return list of parameters
      def paramsList = [
         string(defaultValue: "Jenkins", description: 'Some Name', name: 'NAME'),
         string(defaultValue: "no_title", description: 'Title', name: 'TITLE')
     ]
     paramsList
   }
}
```

from pipeline (or /var/ folder):

```
@Library('jenkins-library') _

import com.company.jenkins.JobParam

List commonParams = JobParam.commonParams()

// your code
```